# Are union types not enforced?

Tags: typescript, typechecking, static-typing, union-types

Shouldn't this fail?

```
class Animal { }
class Person { }

type MyUnion = Number | Person;

var list: Array<MyUnion> = [ "aaa", 2, new Animal() ]; // Shouldn't this fail?

var x: MyUnion = "jjj"; // Shouldn't this fail?
```

Is there a way to enforce type checking in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript handles type compatibility based on `structural subtyping`.

> Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their members

In particular for classes:

> When comparing two objects of a class type, only members of the instance are compared. Static members and constructors do not affect compatibility.

More info at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#classes

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Would one call that "duck typing" ?

Comment: Yes I think you could call it that, Typescript formally refers to it as `structural subtyping`. Wikipedia has a good explanation about duck typing and typescript https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Typescript

Answer (score 3):

It'll fail if `Animal` or `Person` define anything:

```
class Animal { name: string; }
class Person { age: Number; }

type MyUnion = Number | Person;

var list: Array<MyUnion> = [ "aaa", 2, new Animal() ]; // Fails now

var x: MyUnion = "jjj"; // Fails now
```

Since you haven't defined anything in `Animal` or `Person`, a string (or anything, actually), fulfills the contract you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Does it treat Animal / Person as a kind of "any" type?

Comment: Semi-related: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ shows error hints but still runs the code you wrote. Any way to force it to prevent running if errors?

Comment: @KarolDepka I'm unsure of the internals as to whether it's an 'any', however, the contract simply says "I want the object to contain the following members: {}". Since we don't ask for any members to be present, any type can fulfill that request

Comment: @KarolDepka I'm pretty sure the compiler enforces that error by default - I'm unsure about that particular playground site, however.